# Converting a TEXT to dateColumn in Grafana

Tags: postgresql, grafana

New to Grafana.

I have set a Postgres as a data source and am trying to create a sample time series dashboard like so...

```
SELECT
  $__timeGroupAlias(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time),$__interval),
  count(events) AS "events"
FROM source_table
WHERE
  $__timeFilter(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time))
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

The problem is that in my table in postgres the start_time is of a type TEXT and this throws a

```
macro __timeGroup needs time column and interval and optional fill value
```

on Grafana side.

Can someone explain how can my `start_time` be properly converted to DateColumn so that the macros would work?

Thank you

Comment: "*the start_time is of a type TEXT*" - that's a really bad idea. It should be a `timestamp` (or `timestamptz`)  column.

Comment: I couldn't agree with you more, however I have no control over the table and that is the reason why I am asking about the proper way to convert it to TIMESTAMP on grafana side.